# How could I do this? Is it even possible?

Tags: php

So I have a .txt file with over 29k lines of text of names and what I want to do is delete one line for all the lines and add a colon and I can't seem to figure out how I could do this..... I know this is confusing right now but here's what inside my .txt file looks like:

```
William
Kulikowski

Ronald
Kulikowski

Patricia
Kulikowski
```

My text file repeats the pattern above and it's 29k lines long. (yes my .txt file does have those blank lines)

I want to remove one line for all the names and add a colon in my text file for it to look like this:

```
William:Kulikowski

Ronald:Kulikowski

Patricia:Kulikowski
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this... I believe it can be done with PHP and or Command Prompt

Comment: it can be done with bash alone

Comment: why javascript, html tags?

Comment: @MehulMohan A bash? I'm sorry but I do not know what that is.

Comment: @suraj Idk, I'll remove them

Comment: are you in linux/unix environment or windows?

Comment: @suraj I'm running on Windows 10

Comment: @MehulMohan Oh, I see. Bash is a programming language. I don't know the language myself so I'd need help with this

Comment: Sounds like something that could be done using a database, or at least a JSON file, but not just a .txt file...

Comment: @JeremyThille I know it can be done with command prompt too.

Comment: I still need help with this although. I haven't figured this out yet.

Comment: Yeah, and it can be done with a pile of post-it too, but you should consider something more adapted to handle 29k entries.

Comment: @JeremyThille Oh I didn't know it couldn't handle it, my bad. Got any ideas on how to do this though?

Comment: Using command prompt? No idea, sorry :/

Comment: What have you tried so far? We won't write code for you, but we'll help you if you at least try. For what it's worth, I'd probably do this in python (because it's the language that I'm most comfortable with). I'd read the file into an array then do some simple array manipulation to remove newline characters from the end of certain rows. Have a try and a google, and if you end up writing anything in Python and you run into any errors then I could give you a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$f = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
$name = "";
while ($l = fgets($f)) {
    $l = trim($l);
    if ($l != '') {
        if ($name == "")
            $name = $l;
        else
            $name .= ":$l";
    }
    else {
        // this displays the name, you should write to a file replacing <br> with \n
        echo $name."<br><br>";
        $name = "";
    }
}
if ($name != "")
    echo $name."<br><br>";
fclose($f);
?>
```

Comment: I'll try this, Thanks!